# php update into mysql missing something

Tags: php, database, select, mysqli

I'm trying to update product information into the mysql database from edit page, but I'm showing it does not doing anything and even is not showing any errors.

What did I miss?

```
<?php 
$dbcs = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "shopping");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbcs))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Parse the form data and update company information to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $pid = $_POST['thisID'];
    $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
    $product_category = $_POST['product_category'];
    $product_product_retail_price = $_POST['product_retail_price'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];

    // See if that company name is an identical match to another company in the system
    $sql = "UPDATE product SET
    product_name='$product_name', 
    product_category='$product_category', 
    product_retail_price='$product_retail_price',
    product_price='$product_price'
    WHERE product_id='$pid'" or die(mysql_error());  

    header("location: product.php");

    exit();
}


// Gather these companies full information for inserting automatically into the edit form below on page
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id='$targetID' LIMIT 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
               $product_id = $row["product_id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $product_category = $row["product_category"];
             $product_retail_price = $row["product_retail_price"];
             $product_price = $row["product_price"];
             $screenshot =$row["screenshot"];
        }
}

mysqli_close($dbcs);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "UPDATE product SET
product_name='$product_name', 
product_category='$product_category', 
product_retail_price='$product_retail_price',
product_price='$product_price'
WHERE product_id='$pid'";

$query= mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);

if(!$query)
{
print "error";

}
else 
{
header("your page link");
}
```

p.s Thankx for correction Hanky Panky:)

Comment: Wrong, connection comes first and query comes second

Comment: This is not `mysql_query`, this is `mysqli_query` with an `i` and its better to check at http://php.net/mysqli_query than w3schools

Comment: w3schools hasn't heard of MySQLI yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... Maybe run  `$result = mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);` after defining the insert $sql?

Also, use the die() after the mysqli_query() not in the $sql string definition.

Additionally, run all those vars through mysqli_real_escape_string() before using them in the query.

Comment: you guys thanks for your help i learned something new. i have solved it. again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$sql = "UPDATE product SET
    product_name='$product_name', 
    product_category='$product_category', 
    product_retail_price='$product_retail_price',
    product_price='$product_price'
    WHERE product_id='$pid'" or die(mysql_error());
```

You are not executing that query. Execute it with `mysqli_query()`

```
$sql = "UPDATE product SET
    product_name='$product_name', 
    product_category='$product_category', 
    product_retail_price='$product_retail_price',
    product_price='$product_price'
    WHERE product_id='$pid'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);
```